# Asian toasting seeds

Tags: ingredient-selection

if a recipe says Asian toasting seeds how can I find out what is in the mix? Is there a definite selection of seeds and in what ratio? I have seen pouches for sale on the net but would like to make up my own if possible

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Do you want to know what's in a particular brand of mix? Or are you wanting to know what to use if a recipe calls for Asian toasting seeds as an ingredient?

Answer (score 2):

There's no exact definition of asian toasting seeds that I know of, but most mixes I've seen are geared more for curries with cumin, sesame, and black onion seeds as a common base. To that base I've seen poppy, black mustard, yellow mustard, fenugreek, and lovage (ajwain) seeds.

I have all of these except lovage, but kept separate and I mix them together when I cook depending on the flavors I want. You can make your own mix in less than a minute each time. If you do want to make a basic mix then do 3 parts cumin seed, 2 parts sesame, one part black onion, and one part black mustard seed. If you use yellow mustard do a 1/2 part as it's much stronger.